# How to view unreleased shared memory opened by shm_open

Tags: c++, linux, ipc, shared-memory

I am using "shm_open" API for creating a shared memory segment. I can see the shared memory segment listed under "/dev/shm", and everything works as expected. However, I don't see it using "ipcs -m".
If I delete this shared memory segment, for example by "rm -f /dev/shm/my_shared_mem", it is removed from "/dev/shm", but it is not being released until the last process using it detaches it.

How can I view unreleased shared memory segments allocated by "shm_open"?

Thanks,